# Changing __AdditionalEmailAttribute4

Tags: google-analytics

in exact target we're using google analytics for all of our campaigns.

We've also just started implementing dynamic content and we would like to track different results based of the dynamic content.

So we would like to track these different content in google analytics, to do this we need to change the 'utm_campaign' value. Which we have the 'utm_campaign' value as the __AdditionalEmailAttribute4.

How would we best do this? Below is the code I'm working on, however it does not change the utm_campaign.

```
%%[ VAR @utm SET @utm = __AdditionalEmailAttribute4 IF (Gender == 'N') THEN 
utm == "20180615_DynamicContentTest_N" ENDIF ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about google analytics in this context but your amp-script has an error. 
Changing your code to this might be your solution:

```
%%[
    VAR @utm
    SET @utm = __AdditionalEmailAttribute4
    IF (@Gender == 'N') THEN 
        SET @utm = "20180615_DynamicContentTest_N"
    ENDIF
]%%
```

Since i dont know what AdditionalEmailAttribute4 is i guess its either a DataExtensionValue with the collumn named EmailAttribute4, than it would be `Set @utm = [EmailAttribute4]` or its an something else like a variable then it would have to be something like `Set @utm = AttributeValue(@__AdditionalEmailAttribute4)` or set `utm = v(@__AdditionalEmailAttribute4)`.

Variables are set with Set @utm and not like utm == "value". I belief thats your issue here. Furthermore variables cannot be set with `==`. `==` is an boolean expression that compares values. And you cannot compare Gender to a value. You either have to compare the @Gender variable or the [Gender] DataExtension-value.